# How exactly linking works and what exactly i am doing wrong here

Tags: c, compiler-errors, undefined-reference, function-declaration

I am new to C and multi source files code.
I have a header file `prog.h` and source file `prog.c` in those `name` and `age` are declared using `extern` keyword with `set_data` and `print_data` are accessing them in `main.c`. But it showing some linking error.
What exactly i am doing wrong here?

prog.h

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <error.h>

#define ERROR(s) perror(s)
#define BUFF 1024

extern char* name;
extern int age;

void print_data(char* name, int age);`
```

prog.c

```c
#include "prog.h"

void set_data(char* a_name, int a_age)
{
    name = a_name;
    age = a_age;
}

void print_data(char *name, int age)
{
    printf("Name: %s\nAge: %d\n", name, age);
}
```

main.c

```c
#include "prog.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    set_data(argv[1], argv[2]);
    print_data(name, age);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

GCC:

`gcc -o main main.c prog.c`

Error:

```
`main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:6:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘set_data’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    6 |     set_data(argv[1], argv[2]);
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccWK8fek.o: warning: relocation against `name' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccR60C2Q.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `age'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `name'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccWK8fek.o: in function `set_data':
prog.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `name'
/usr/bin/ld: prog.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `age'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have researched online, i have tried using `extern` keyword but, it's not working.

Comment: This is my first post and sorry for if violated any tech enthusiast.

Comment: Please don't tag `c++` for C questions. They are two distinct languages.

Comment: Forgot declare `set_data` function in `prog.h`.

Comment: You are missing a declaration for `set_data` in `prog.h` and there are no definitions for `name` and `age` anywhere in your program. They need to be define in exactly _one_ `.c` file (in addition to the non-defining declarations with `extern` in the header).

Comment: Your header file does not declare the `set_data` function. So, `main.c` has no way of knowing about it. The fix is to declare `set_data` in your header file so that the linker understands it's shared between translation units. In a similar way, the global variables are not defined anywhere. You must declare them `extern` in the header, and then provide a definition for them in `prog.c`.

Comment: What languages are you familiar with?

Comment: @paddy There is no any need to declare the functions with the specifier extern. They by default are external.

Comment: `set_data(argv[1], argv[2]);` If you had a proper prototype visible for that function, your compiler could tell you that `argv[2]` does not match the expected type for second parameter. It is `char*` not `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These declarations of variables

```
extern char* name;
extern int age;
```

are not their definitions. So the compiler issues messages that references to the variables are undefined. You need to define them for example in `prog.c` like

```
char* name;
int age;
```

The declaration of the function `set_data` is absent in the translation unit with `main`. So the compiler issues messages that the function is implicitly declared. Without seeing its declaration the compiler is unable to check whether the function is used correctly. Place the function declaration in thhe header `prog.h` the same way as the function declaration of `print_data`.